# What do the Vedas say about the Earth?

Tags: vedas, earth

This article mentions this about [Earth in Hinduism](https://www.academia.edu/16028337/VEDIC_SCIENCE_AND_ENVIRONMENT)

> Earth is represented as goddess, which feeds everyone. All the forms
>   of earth and of life on it are the children of earth. Rivers, trees
>   animals are attendants of the earth goddess.

What do the Vedas say about the Earth?

Comment: Related not duplicate [Do Vedas say Earth is static?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2010/3500)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Hinduism Earth is sacred and considered as  Mother of all living beings BHUDEVI (भूदेवी). She is also called as Prithivi ,Vasundhara or vasudha  (पृथ्वी ,वसुधरा ,वसुधा).** Hindus revere the earth as a symbol of tolerance forbearance , patience and steadfastness. Mother earth is respected for all her natural resources especially the forests ,herbs ,minirals and the vegetation.

> **समुद्रवसने देवि पर्वतस्तनमण्डले । विष्णुपत्नि नमस्तुभ्यं पादस्पर्शं**
>   **क्षमस्वमे ॥**
>
> Meaning - " O devi ! you are clothed with water , mountains are on
>   your chest , you the consort of Visnu I bow you and ask you to forgive
>   me for standing on you"

Some of the hymns and quotes from various vedic texts are given below -:

**Atharva veda says "The earth is mother ,Firmament the father"**

it further says **" Mata Bhumi putroham prithivyah "  (माता भूमि पुत्रोहं पृथिव्या:) Meaning "Earth is my mother I am her son".**
See  [Here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vVipAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=%22The%20earth%20is%20mother%20,Firmament%20the%20father%22%20atharva%20veda%20sanskrit&source=bl&ots=RsOlVH5VWx&sig=U6WYG2F5BsaPj0WHOAI6mvpHur4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv2IvG4YHPAhWDgI8KHZNrAL4Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22The%20earth%20is%20mother%20%2CFirmament%20the%20father%22%20atharva%20veda%20sanskrit&f=false)

There  are scores of other verses that glorify Mother Earth. The hymn of these verses is known as **"Prithivi Sukta** " in AtharvaVeda .In these verses, prithi is described as vasudhara or vasudha (Possessor of wealth).See [Here](http://www.jaimaa.org/articles/prithvi-sukta-hymn-to-the-earth-atharva-veda/)

> **Hiranyavaksha** ( one with golden bosom ). She is worshipped for
>   providing food and prosperity , sustaning the animal world and for
>   growth of forests and herbs , for providing space for lakes ,rivers
>   and large water bodies. she is discribed as holding Fire (AGNI) in her
>   belly (center of earth).
>
> O Earth - brown, black, red and multi-colored the firm Earth protected
>   by Indra, on this Earth may I stand - unvanquished, unhurt, unslain.
>   This earth, our mother, has nurtured consciousness from the slime of
>   the primeval ocean billions of years ago and has sustained the human
>   race for countless centuries. Will we repay our debts to our mother by
>   converting her into a burnt out cinder circling the sun into eternity?

**" BHU- Suktam (भू-सूक्तं) "**  in "Taittirya Samhita " also  states qualities of mother earth.

> **विश्वस्वं मातरमोषधीनां ध्रुवां भूमिं पृथिवीं धर्मणा धृताम् ।**
>   **शिवां स्योनामनु चरेम विश्वहा ॥**
>
> Vishvasvam Maataram-Ossadhiinaam Dhruvaam Bhuumim Prthiviim Dharmannaa
>   Dhrtaam | Shivaam Syonaam-Anu Carema Vishvahaa ||
>
> **Meaning**:
>   17.1: (Salutations to Mother Earth) The Herbs (Plants) which are like Mothers of the World(who sustains us) grows on the Immovable
>   Earth (Bhumi); the Earth which is held byDharma, ...
>   17.2: ... and in which Auspiciousness gently pervades throughout the World.
>
> **गिरयस्ते पर्वता हिमवन्तोऽरण्यं ते पृथिवि स्योनमस्तु ।**
>   **बभ्रुं कृष्णां रोहिणीं विश्वरूपां ध्रुवां भूमिं पृथिवीमिन्द्रगुप्ताम्** ।
>   **अजीतेऽहतो अक्षतोऽध्यष्ठां पृथिवीमहम् ॥**
>
> Girayas-Te Parvataa Himavanto-[A]rannyam Te Prthivi Syonam-Astu |
>   Babhrum Krssnnaam Rohinniim Vishvaruupaam Dhruvaam Bhuumim
>   Prthiviim-Indra-Guptaam | Ajiite-[A]hato Akssato-[A]dhyasstthaam
>   Prthiviim-Aham ||
>
> **Meaning:**
>   11.1: (Salutations to Mother Earth) O Mother Earth, May Your Hills and Snow-Clad Mountains (spread its coolness within us);
>   May Your Forests spread its delight within us,
>   11.2: You present a Vishwarupa with Your many colours - Babhru (Brown) (of mountains),Krishna (Blue) (of rivers), Rohini (Red) (of flowers);
>   (But behind all these enchanting appearances) O Mother Earth, You are
>   like Dhruva - Firm and Immovable; And You are protected by Indra,
>   11.3: (On Your firm foundation) Which is Unconquered, Unslayed and Unbroken Whole, Istand firm (and whole, O
>   Mother).
>
> **विश्वंभरा वसुधानी प्रतिष्ठा हिरण्यवक्षा जगतो निवेशनी** ।
>   **वैश्वानरं बिभ्रती भूमिरग्निमिन्द्रऋषभा द्रविणे** **नो दधातु ॥**
>
> Vishvambharaa Vasudhaanii Pratisstthaa Hirannya-Vakssaa Jagato
>   Niveshanii | Vaishvaanaram Bibhratii Bhuumir-Agnim-Indra-Rssabhaa
>   Dravinne No Dadhaatu ||
>
> **Meaning**:
>   6.1: (Salutations to Mother Earth) She is Vishwambhara (All-Bearing), She is Vasudhaa(Producer of all Wealth), She is Pratishtha (Foundation
>   on which we live), She isHiranyavaksha (of Golden Bosom) and
>   the Dwelling Place of the World,
>   6.2: She holds the Vaishvanara (The Universal Fire) within Her, the Fire which empowers Indra and Rishabha; May the Mother Earth
>   bestow on us (the splendour of that Fire and make us strong).
>
> **असंबाधं बध्यतो मानवानां यस्या उद्वतः प्रवतः समं बहु ।**
>   **नानावीर्या ओषधीर्या** **बिभर्ति पृथिवी नः प्रथतां राध्यतां नः ॥**
>
> Asambaadham Badhyato Maanavaanaam Yasyaa Udvatah Pravatah Samam Bahu |
>   Naanaa-Viiryaa Ossadhiiryaa Bibharti Prthivii Nah Prathataam
>   Raadhyataam Nah ||
>
> **Meaning**:
>   2.1: (Salutations to Mother Earth) Who extends Unimpeded Freedom (both outer and inner) to Human Beings through Her
>   Mountains, Slopes and Plains,
>   2.2: She bears many Plants and Medicinal Herbs of various Potencies; May She extend Her Riches to us (and make us healthy).[Bhumi-Suktam ,भूमि-सूक्तं](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/bhumi-bhumi_sukta.php)

**Gayatries for Bhumi Devi - (भू-गायत्री मंत्र)**

**ॐ धनुर्धराययी च विद्महे  सर्व सिद्धि:च धीमहि तन्नो धरा प्रचोदयात ।।**
Om Dhanurdharayi ch vidmahey serva siddhi ch dhimahi tanno dhara prachodayat.

**ॐ वसुंधाराय विद्महे भूतधात्रीय धीमहि तन्नो भूमि प्रचोदयात ।।**
Om Vasundharaya vidhmaye bhutdhatriya dhimahi tanno bhumi prachodayat.

[Bhu Gayatri 1](http://www.dhevee.org/bhoomi-devi-gayatri-mantra/) &
[2](http://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/goddess-bhumidevi)

Comment: @Amitsaxena - I have reformatted answer with additon of sanskrit shlokas ,   links. Also consider accepting answer if you think it has what you are expecting.

Comment: One more verse in MahaNarayana upanishad is " Ashvakrantay Rathakranthay VishnuKranthay Vasundhara | Sirasa daritha devi rakshashva mam padhey padhey ||

Comment: @Krishna - yes , thanks for the shloka :)

Comment: @@SwiftPushkar - Bhu Suktam further says "Vishnu pathnim mahim devIm mAdhavIm mAdhavaPriyam |Lakshmi Priya sakhim Devim Naamam achyutha Vallabham" Please do add these verses also to your answer. Also add Bhu - Gayatri , " om dhanurdharayai vidmahe ....etc"

Comment: @Krishna - Thanks again.BHU Gayatries are added in answer ,as you have suggested. :)

Comment: @@SwiftPushkar -I think, the verses you have quoted are from Atharva veda. The link you provided also saysthe same.  It is called Bhoomi Suktham. Bhu  Suktham is from Taittriya Samhita and also Rig Veda. It starts with "bhUmirbhUmnA dyaur-variNA antariksham mahitvA ..." Though both sukthams are addressed to Goddess Bhu only. So, please change the your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> The famous Bhu suktham is part of Pancha suktham and appears in Taittriya Samhita and also Rigveda.

This BHU Suktha is part of
Taittiriya samhita , Khanda 1, Prapathaka -5, Anuvakaha - 3  &
Taittiriya Brahmana , Aatakam - 3, Prasna - 1, Anuvakaha - 2
( The above source details are given in a book called Svasvara VedA mantras Published by Ramakrishna mutt)

> ***bhUmirbhUmnA dyaur-variNA antariksham mahitvA |
>   upasthe te devyadite agnim annAdam annAdyAyAdadhe*** || 1 ||
>
> **Meaning**:   Oh BhUmi devi! You are called BhUmi because you are rich in all kinds of wealth. You are vast in Your breadth and length, lofty through Your vaibhavam and are resplendent and glorious in the milky way as well in all the space that is desired by all! Oh Devi, whose source (mother) is 'aditi' implying a good force as opposed to the evil force as You are ever ready to help us by being nearby, because of your unlimited compassion  and your ever-forgiving attitude . Oh Devi who cannot be split by anyone! In the middle of You between the sky and the earth, I invoke you through AdhAna agni, who can consume the offered havis.
>
> ***Ayam gau: prSnirakramIdasanan mAtaram puna:|pitaram ca prayan suva:*** || 2||
>
> **Meaning:**  With His rays, the radiant Sun comes to our side like the food giving protective Mother and blesses us with the fields rich in crops and ascends to the sky and blesses us from there with the rain like the Father who nourishes us.
>
> ***trigum SaddhAma virAjati vAk patangAya SiSriye | 
>   pratyasya vaha dyubhi:*** || 3 ||
>
> **Meaning**:  With the movement  of the sUryan, the world shines with light for 12 hours.  May my speech in the form of eulogy reach Him as He moves rapidly in the sky! Oh Lord Preceptor sUrya! May Thou chase away my aparAdhAs and blemishes with the lustre of Your rays! May You be cool to me and favour me with health for eloquence in speech and May Thou accept the havis offered by me through Your jvAlas!
>
> ***asya prANAt apAnatyanta: carati rocanA |
>    vyakhyan mahisha: suva:*** || 4 ||
>
> **Meaning**: His (sUrya’s) lustre spreads from morning to evening, in between the earth and the sky and moves inside and out through the vital airs and invigorates as a lifegiver by ( Bhumi) Devi's grace. He reveals the great world of svarga for those dear to Him.
>
> ***yattvA kruddha: paro vapa manyunA yadavartyA |
>   sukalpamagne tat tava punastvoddIpayAmasi*** || 5 ||
>
> **Meaning:** Oh sUrya! Out of the extreme anger (fury) born out of my enmity/poverty, I might have slipped in my prayers for You. Oh fire god! By your industriousness/entrepreneurship, You sow the seed and pour water for the Earth to grow! (agnerApa: adbhya: prthivI - taittirIyopanishad). From now, I vow to eulogize You in a way that will please You. Please accept our worship as well done, accept it and please be more effulgent again! (according to scriptures, the sun's brilliance is transferred to the fire from the evening twilight to the morning twilight-hence the sun is fire! Supporting kAlidAsa's words in the first verse of the fourth canto of raghuvamSa - dinAnte nihitam teja: savitrA hutASana:)
>
> ***yat te manyuparoptasya prthivImanu dadhvase |
>   AdityA viSve taddevA: vasavaSca samAbharan*** || 6 ||
>
> **Meaning**: Because of your anger from which emanated the earth and grew, May you sustain it! May the vasus, rudrAs, AdityAs and ViSvadevAs come together and take the collective responsibility to return to me my bhagavat bhakti that I threw away on ground because of my anger!
>
> ***medinI devI vasundharA syAd vasudhA devI vAsavI | 
>   brahmavarcasa: pitrNAm Srotram cakshurmana:*** || 7 ||
>
> **Meaning**: She might be addressed by Her many names: medinI, devI, VasundharA, VasudhA, VaasavI (as indrA as a representative, activates) but She is for sure with divine spiritual splendour and is the ear, eye and the mind of the pitrs (manes).
>
> ***devI hiraNya-garbhiNI devI prasUvarI*** | 8 |
>
> **Meaning**: The goddess of Earth (Mother Earth) is pregnant with the whole universal gold egg, as the best creator and the best sustainer.
>
> ***rasane satyAyane sIda | 
>   samudravatI sAvitrI ha no devI mahyangI*** | 9 |
>
> **Meaning:** May you reach and reside in my tongue to make it truthful! You (She as the Mother Earth) comprise of all the seas and hence You are called 'samudravatI', and You are named 'sAvitrI' since You are associated with the Sun by Your wonderful brightness. You are our presiding deity benevolent, self-luminous and a benign care-taker, day and night.
>
> ***maho dharaNI mahodhyadhishThA: Srnge Srnge yaj~ne yaj~ne vibhIshiNI*** l 10
>
> **Meaning**: You are the great Mother Earth (who bears everything without a grudge or murmur!) established on a firm-footing (on His side in standing posture  and on the horn of the great boar, varAha) on the top of every creation and fearlessly in every sacrifice (as also like yajno vai vishNu:) thus assuring the devotees complete protection from morbid and mundane fears and never threatening the devotees like a tIkshNa-daNDa-dhara: (a tyrant/ dictator)
>
> ***indrapatnI vyApinI surasaridiha vAyumatI jalaSayanI SriyandhA | 
>   rAjA satyandho parimedinI Svo paridhattam gAya*** | 11
>
> **Meaning**: She is the consort of the Supreme lord, pervading everywhere (omnipresent) and the divine river (mandAkinI/gangA) here on the earth, thus purifying the errant/erring souls. She is full of movement like air, brisk and breath of everyone to be alive.  she reclines on the water (payodhi), holds the riches in abundance associated with the goddess of fortune. You are truly alive, on the top of the earth all around.
>
> ***vishNu patnIm mahIm devIm mAdhavIm mAdhavapriyAm |
>   lakshmI priyasakhIm devIm namAmyacyuta-vallabhAm*** l 12
>
> **Meaning**: We salute Goddess BhUmi (mahIm devIm), the consort of VishNu; we salute that mAdhavI, who is dear to Maadhava ( Lord Vishnu ) and who is the dearest friend of LakshmI devi. Our salutations are to BhUmi devi, who has vAllabhyam (vaSIkaraNa) over Her Lord, acyuta (Lord Vishnu)
>
> ***om dhanurdharAyai vidmahe sarvasiddhyai ca dhImahi |
>   tanno dharA pracodayAt*** || 13 ||
>
> **Meaning:** We worship Her by knowing Her as One who (wields the bow and looks also like a bow, lean in the middle) is adorning the bow. For that purpose we meditate upon the One who blesses us with all success (sarva siddhi). May that dharaNi dharA/BhUmi devI, prompt us for that meditation!
>
> ***SrNvantI SroNAmamrtasya gopAm | 
>   puNyAmasyA upaSruNomi vAcam*** | 14
>
> **Meaning:** As a Mother, she carefully listens to all our appeals for ever and she is the hidden and holy river of nectar; and as a bhaktA, i never miss hearing Her words of solace and being comforted by being near Her.
>
> ***mahIm devIm vishNu-patnImajUryAm | 
>   pratIcImenAgum havisha yajAma: |
>   tredhA vishNururugAyo vicakrame | 
>   mahIm divam prthivImantariksham*** | 15
>
> **Meaning**: Let us all pray to this Goddess of Earth, the consort of Lord VishNu especially in sacrifices (yajna) by offering the oblations of food (havis) which will in turn, come back to us as Her grants. Lord VishNu with the gigantic stature (by incarnating as trivikrama) treaded the three steps (the great strides) and measured the fourteen worlds inclusive of the Earth (mahIm prthivIm) and the sky (divam and antariksham).
>
> ***tacchroNaiti Srava icchamAnA | 
>   puNyagum Slokam yajamAnAya krNvatI*** || 16 ||
>
> **Meaning:** The Goddess of Earth thus is paying utmost attention faithfully to the devotees' prayers with a great care and involved interest sans pains and transfers the holy eulogies to make the Lord, our Master hear and bless us

For more details and inner meanings and commentary please refer to the following [link](http://www.sadagopan.org/SriHayagrivan/SH095%20-%20Bhu%20suktam.pdf)

In **MahaNarayanopanishad**, also called **Yajniki Upanishad** ( tenth Prapathaka of **Taittiriya Aranyaka**, which is part of **Krishna Yajur Veda**) the following verses are used to describe the greatness of Bhumi devi

> ***Ashvakranthey Rathakranthey Vishnukranthey VasunDharA |SiraSA darithA devi RakshaSva mam Padhey Padhey*** ||30
>
> Meaning : O' Goddess VasunDharA, you bear the tramping of horses and chariots and the strides of Lord Vishnu. I bear you with reverence on my head; protect me always.
>
> ***UdhrutAsi varAhena krishnena shathabAhunam|
>   Bhumirdhenurdharanee lokadArinee*** || 31
>
> Meaning : You are lifted up by Krishna in the form of VarAha. You are well known as Bhumi, Dhenu, Dharani, and the supporter of all worlds.
>
> ***Mrutakay hana may Papam yenmaya dhushkrutham  krutham |Tvaya hatena papayna Jeevami sarada: satham |
>   Mrutakay Dehi may prustim tvayi sarvam prathistitham*** || 32
>
> Meaning : O' Goddess Earth, destroy my sin: destroy whatever misdeed is done by me. My sins having been destroyed by you , may I live a hundred autumns. O' Earth, bestow on me nourishment - everything is established in you.
>
> ***Gandhadvaram durAdarsham nityapushtam kareeshineem | Isvareegam sarvabhutanam tamihopahvaye Sriyam***|| 33
>
> Meaning :I invoke the Goddess Earth  to bless us; O' Goddess who art the ruler of all entities, who art known by odour, who art invincible by sins, who art ever full and who art associated with cow dung and others

Comment: @Keshav  and Moderators, Why the down vote? Strange.. I think, this forum doesn't like genuine answers?