# Who were the parents of Bhumi Devi(Prithvi)?

Tags: devi, earth, varaha, parents, bhumi

Who were the parents of Bhumi Devi,the Goddess of Earth? (If any) Can someone say in which purana her origin is mentioned?

Comment: One of the answers [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12483/what-do-the-vedas-say-about-the-earth/) mentions that her mother is Aditi.

Comment: Oh ok! So sage Kashyapa would  be the father? But what about her origins?

Comment: Bhudevi is a primordial element of nature - in fact, nature is a manifestation of Bhudevi - so she has always existed. Therefore I don't think she has an origin story.

Comment: All the origin stories of most deities are always based on "Kalpa level". Since there are infinite Kalpas before and infinite after this current *Sri ShevtaVaraha Kalpa* - thus ultimately it becomes an equivalent "science-based Chicken-Egg problem."

Answer (score 4):

In one Samvarta Smriti (Samhita) verse (74th from Chapter 1), Earth is mentioned as an offspring of Lord Vishnu.

> The first offspring of the Fire is gold ; **Vishnu's offspring is the
> earth** ; and kine are the daughters of the Sun. By him, who makes
> gifts of gold, earth and kine, three regions are given away. (74)

But this is surprising considering the fact that Lord Vishnu, in his Varaha avatara, has Bhu Devi as his consort.

EDIT:

I'm unable to find the entire Samavrata Smriti (in English) online currently although I have downloaded it years back. But I have found it in Sanskrit only [here](https://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/08Samvartta_Smriti.pdf).

The verse I have given above can be located in Sanskrit on page 6 (out of 18) of the PDF.

> [image]
>
> Agnyer apatyam prathamam suvarnam bhur-vaishnavi suryasutascha gavah
> |
>  Lokas-trayastena bhavanti datta yah gashcha mahishcha daddat ||

The translation is already given above. In this verse Earth is mentioned as Bhu (in Bhur-Vaishnavi) and as Mahi as well (in mahishcha). The first half of the verse is talking about apatya (or offspring) of Agni, Vishnu and Surya respectively.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give the link to the entire text which you're referring to?

Comment: @TranquilChaos I was unable to find the entire text in English in my first search attempt. But see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lord shiva n mata parvati are the parents of bhoodevi. Not only her but they are also the parents of the panch mahabhootam which includes water, air, fire, sky and earth. So lord shiva is also called panchbhooteshwara which the one from whom all the five elements were created and who have control over them and he is also called bhoodeva which means the lord of the earth. There are also temples of lord panchmahabhooteshwaram or panchbhooteshwar or bhooteshwar am in the south. Which also is mentioned in shri ghagwat gita. Om....

According to Rigveda...

The verse RV 6.49.10 calls Rudra as **" The Father of the Universe" (bhuvanasya pitaraṃ)**

> ***bhuvanasya pitaraṃ** ghīrbhirābhī rudraṃ divā vardhayā rudramaktau*
>
> *bṛhantaṃ ṛṣvamajaraṃ suṣumnaṃ ṛdhagh ghuvema kavineṣitāsaḥ (RV 6 :49:10 ) [38]*

Translation:

> *Rudra by day, Rudra at night we honour with these our songs, **the Universe's Father.**
> Him great and lofty, blissful, undecaying let us call specially as the Sage impels us ( RV 6.49.10)[39]*

The verse RV 2.33.9 calls Rudra as "The Lord or Sovereign of the Universe" (īśānādasya bhuvanasya)

> *sthirebhiraṅghaiḥ pururūpa ughro babhruḥ śukrebhiḥ pipiśehiraṇyaiḥ*
>
> ***īśānādasya bhuvanasya** bhūrerna vā u yoṣad rudrādasuryam ( Rig veda 2:33:9 )[40]*

Translation:

> *With firm limbs, multiform, the strong, the tawny adorns himself with bright gold decorations:
> The strength of Godhead never departs from Rudra, him **who is Sovereign of this world, the mighty***.[41]

I hope this explains that lord shiva is the father of universe so maa bhoodevi (planet earth) n all other planets were created during the creation of universe itself by the tandav n laasya of lord shiva n maa gauri which was again stated in Shiva Maha Purana. That's why bring the purusha and prakriti they are also called jagat pita and jagat mata.

**Edit.:**

> *“somaḥ pavate janitā matīnāṃ janitā divo **janitā pṛthivyāḥ** |
> janitāghnerjanitā sūryasya janitendrasya janitota viṣṇoḥ |” (Rig Veda IX.96.5)*
>
> *“**Father of sacred chants, Soma( Lord Siva or Rudra) flows onwards, **the Father of the Earth**, Father of the Celestial region: Father of Agni, the creator of Surya, the Father who gave birth to Indra and Vishnu.**”*

See this:
https://m.patrika.com/gwalior-news/1000-year-old-shiva-temple-are-mentioned-in-geeta-1361061/
https://isha.sadhguru.org/mahashivratri/shiva/shivas-names-108-shiva-names-with-meanings/
https://www.templepurohit.com/hindu-temples/pancha-bhoota-lingams/
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Bhoota_Stalam
https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/140104-siva-the-siva-purana-retold
https://www.templepurohit.com/kashmiri-shaivism/amp/

Comment: Could you cite the references please?

Comment: Here it's not literally means offspring but yeah he created them n here are some proofs...
https://www.templepurohit.com/hindu-temples/pancha-bhoota-lingams/
And here see the names bhooteshwar n bhoodev and their meaning...
https://isha.sadhguru.org/mahashivratri/shiva/shivas-names-108-shiva-names-with-meanings/. This is a paragraph from rigveda.
Rudra is fierce and destructive like a terrible beast. He is the ruddy boar of heaven. He is exalted, strong, strongest of the strong, unassailable, unsurpassed in might, rapid and swift. He is young and never ages. He is called asura or the great

Comment: asura of heaven. He is self-glorious, rules over heroes, and is a lord (īśāna) of this vast world. He is the source (father) of everything.
Rudra by day, Rudra at night we honour with these our songs, the Universe's Father. Him great and lofty, blissful, un-decaying let us call specially as the Sage impels us. - Rigveda 6.49.10... I hope u get this now... That lord shiva is the father of everyone and everything...he is everything n he is in everything...

Comment: Like 1st site which is a temple of panch bhooteshwar in south...Also see this where the temple is described in bhagvat gita... https://m.patrika.com/gwalior-news/1000-year-old-shiva-temple-are-mentioned-in-geeta-1361061/

Comment: Welcome to HSE! We insist on citing references from valid scriptures. You can learn more about answering questions from the help centre as well as [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange). Also Please see Rickross’ answer above for a better idea on how to answer.

Comment: I have give reference to rigveda '6.49.10' please check that n have a better idea for yourself. Check the Vedas n try to be courteous next time n learn how to reply next time instead of being rude. Its ok u can check rickross's answer for better knowledge n  no need check mine. If rigveda is not a valid scripture than than I insist don't check my answet what else can I say here. Do u want me to delete my answer.? if yes than just say so.

Comment: Firstly no one is being rude. The Rig Vedic reference is a praise about Mahadeva. There is only one line which says he is the father of everything. This is a typical aspect when praising a god as supreme Brahman. The question of the OP specifically asks who is the direct parent of Bhudevi, not that everyone and everything originated from the Brahman. If someone asks a person their father’s name they can’t say Shiva. It’s not a valid answer (unless it’s Ganesha Skanda), because they intend to ask about the direct father. Yes Brahman is the lord and father of everything but not in this context.

Comment: Secondly the reference must form part of your answer and not a comment. It would be really nice as a new user to read the guidelines. By telling you to read guidelines I’m hoping for new users to become part of the site and learn the ways around here, it’s not a malicious remark on your answer. It is extending a helping hand.

Comment: 1stly, Yes u were being rude but it's ok leave it n 2ndly, I have just checked the guidelines n it is saying that it is right also in in context if I can prove proof. There is a point saying that any one can say that maa ganga is holy just because she is being touched by shiva n vishnu themselves but I have to give proof in written something like that. Even they are also saying tv serials can also be a reference. N here u r not asking about about any person but instead u r asking who is the father of the planet earth n I am telling u that lord rudra is the father of the universe itself.

Comment: Even his name's also suggest that panchbhooteshwar or bhooteshwar (from whom the panch bhootas have originated n who has mastery over them) n bhoodeva (lord of the earth). Even the temples in South also suggests that n there is also a reference of it in gita as I have shared the link. Even in Shiva puran it is said that from the tandav n laaya of shiva n shakti everything including all the planets have originated.

Answer (score 1):

According to various passages in the Rig Veda, the earth (pṛthivi) was not born.  Rather, it was manufactured by 'the poet' (kavi), seemingly referring to Tvastr, who is a sort of maker-god.

This is most clearly expressed in RV 1.160.4 -
"This is the most skilful of skilful gods who produced the omnibenevolent Sky and Earth,
Who carefully measured out the two atmospheres [and] adorned them with undecaying pillars."

RV 4.56.3 and RV 3.54.6 also refer to this same event.  All the devas were then born from the Sky and Earth.  [I have written a bit more about it here.](https://medium.com/desiretothink/creation-in-the-rig-veda-8772c3569d20)

Comment: Welcome to HSE! It would be really nice if rather than a link only, the relevant part is copied to the answer as well. Same applies to all answers