# Do mountains stabilize the Earth?

Tags: story

In another question, someone asked [if mountains have wings](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/did-mountains-use-to-have-wings?newreg=336b1ea84a9d4e5caab2a66bb8bfbfeb) and it seems to be a widely reported idea. The basic idea, which you can see from the link, is that the mountains used to have wings but them flying around was causing issues so Indra cut off their wings, leading the mountains to joining the Earth's surface and staying there. However, I'm interested in the sources for the report that this act also caused the mountains to stabilize or help fix the Earth. For example, Michael Witzel writes;

"After the permanent separation of heaven and earth, creation continues with the actual formation of land (cf. §3.3). Usually this is done with the help of a demiurge, such as the Vedic Indra, who created land some time after he had stemmed apart Heaven and Earth: the Earth, floating on the ocean, was shaky still. As mentioned, Indra cut off the wings of the mountains that used to fly around and sit down here and there. **Once the mountains sat down permanently, the Earth became fixed.**" (Michael Witzel, The Origins of the World's Mythologies, Oxford 2012, pg. 137)

Can someone provide me with the specific sources describing the stability caused to the Earth by these mountains? It doesn't necessarily have to be connected with Indra.

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22600/12304

Comment: @YDS thanks for that